# Rails : syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following piece of codes gives error:

```
/home/nish/staging/app/views/product_search/_products.html.erb:31: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

<% if products.any? %>
<%= render :partial=> 'product_listing_feature', :locals => {:scope => scope, :scope_type => scope_type} %>
<ul class="products" data-hook class="products">
    <div id="ql_product"></div>
    <div class="page">
    <taxons.each do |taxon|>
      <% taxonProducts = Array.new %>
      <% products.each do |product| %>
        <%@ptaxon = product.get_taxonomy%>
        <%if @ptaxon == taxonomy%>
          <% taxonProducts.push(product) %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <%= render :partial=> 'product_listing', :locals=>{:collection=> taxonProducts} %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

I found out that this error occurs when there is an extra `<%end%>` in the code. I feel I have used `end`s at appropriate places. Unable to figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<taxons.each do |taxon|>
```

should be :

```
<% taxons.each do |taxon| %>
```

It's just plain text as you written it, not ruby interpreted.